# What's up with "Destination host unreachable" from my own IP?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ping

The internet died at the office today. Figured I'd start a ping to see when things started working again.

```
ping 1.1.1.1 /t
```

For the most part I'm getting

```
Request timed out.
```

But then for a short while I got sporadic cases of

```
Reply from 192.168.98.64: Destination host unreachable.
```

Ran `ipconfig`, and turns out that's my own IP... which made me curious... what does that mean exactly? Why don't I always get that one, or the other, reply? What's the difference between "timed out" and "unreachable"? Why did it come from my own computer and not the default gateway or something?

Comment: *Request timed out.* means your station send ping, and not accept pong. *Reply from 192.168.98.64: Destination host unreachable.* means your station checks default (or partial) gateway availability with negative result.

Comment: Your computer replied to itself because your own route table does not contain a way to reach 1.1.1.1. You can check your route table with the command "route print". Post that if you are having trouble understanding it.